# Webdriverio throws undefined element for row in a table

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

I have to click on a button located in the first row of a table after navigating from another page. After I go to my page I check that the rows in the table are not undefined by using waitUntil.

```
    waitUntil(
      () => {
        return (          
           myPage.myList.myRows != undefined
        );
      },
      Timeouts.SixtySeconds,
      'Rows were not found',
    );
```

however if I try to do anything on the row by using `myPage.myList.myRows[0]` I get an undefined error for myRows[0]. I have checked again and again the locators and everything seems to be fine. I am at a loss about what to do.

Comment: What is leading to myPage.MyList.myRows to be updated during the timeout period?  Shouldn't you be issuing another query to see if the DOM has updated?

Comment: Hi Dave, I am not sure I understand your answer. You are basically saying that the myPage.myList.myRows != undefined is not ok and that I should be using something else? Can you suggest what?

Comment: See the docs here: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil/.  You must issue the element query within the waitUntil callback to fetch whether the rows have been populated.  The return value from the callback is a boolean to indicate whether the condition has been met